# Yii2: Method Not Allowed (#405) while logout user

Tags: yii2

I am loging out user through following code. This is my view code behind logout button:

```
<li>
   <a href="<?= Url::to(['site/logout'])?>">
    <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Log out
   </a>
 </li>
```

My controller code is:

```
public function actionLogout()
{
    Yii::$app->user->logout();

    $model = new LoginForm();
    $this->layout = 'index';
    return $this->render('login', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

In the logout it shows me:

> Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request
>   methods: POST.

What is it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Seems like you have `VerbFilter` attached to `logout` action in your `SiteController`:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [            
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

That means this action can requested only with POST method, and you are requesting with GET, that's why exception #405 is thrown.

Either remove this from `VerbFilter` or add `data-method` attribute to request with POST:

```
<a href="<?= Url::to(['site/logout'])?>" data-method="post">...</a>
```

**Update:** Another reason of this problem can be missing dependency for [yii\web\YiiAsset](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-yiiasset.html). Make sure it's included in `AppAsset`:

```
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    ...
];
```

`YiiAsset` provides `data-method` attribute feature which gives possibility to link act as a form with action `post` by writing less code. Without asset obviously link will act as regular link and standard GET request will be sent.

Comment: Tried the first one before. but the second on is good...thanks

Comment: I had the same problem today (May 2015) downloading and installing the Yii2 advanced template (I just started learning Yii yesterday). The removal of the post requirement from the verb filter works for me, but when I inspected the main.php inside templates for frontend and backend, both already use a post method per @arogachev''s second suggestion (like so 'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post'])...so why is the error happening in the first place? I'd rather not remove the requirement of POST-ing to logout.

Comment: @sunny I know this is a bit late but check that your assetbundle loaded with the view includes the yii\web\YiiAsset. This is because the data-method attribute is validated via yii's custom javascript/jquery routine.

Comment: Maybe I forgot to give credit to Kartik V, I had the same problem which I solved using his suggestion [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/55483-method-not-allowed-405-solved/)

Comment: Data-method is not working even if yii js code for creating a form and making post request is present. But the same code is working on front-end but not in my module. I can't figure it out.

Comment: Thank You  **data-method="post"** is easy to implement !

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a custom template

```
                     'items' => [
                        [
                            'label' => 'Logout',
                            'url' => ['/user/security/logout'],
                            'template' => '<a href="{url}" data-method="post">{label}</a>',
                        ],
                    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

u can change the view code and echo instead of

```
<li>
   <a href="<?= Url::to(['site/logout'])?>">
    <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Log out
   </a>
 </li>
```

this one:

```
    <?= Html::a('<i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>',
           ['/site/logout'],
           ['class'=>'btn btn-default btn-flat']), //optional* -if you need to add style
           ['data' => ['method' => 'post',]])
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must only replace 'logout' => ['post'], with 'logout' => ['get']. In this way your error will be solved.

This way works only with Yii Framework version 2.

- See more at: http://tutorials.scrisoft.com/solve-this-error-method-not-allowed-this-url-can-only-handle-the-following-request-methods-post/#sthash.fQmwYPJH.dpuf

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Nav::widget` to generate menus, the logout item should have `linkOptions` specified:

```
[
  'label' => '<i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>Logout',
  'url' => ['/logout'],
  'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post'],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Following works too assuming you might extra class and `data-method` attribute.

```
<?= 
    Html::a(
        'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')', 
        ['/site/logout'], 
        ['class' => 'ui inverted button', 'data-method' => 'post']                
    );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is working for AdminLTE template.

```
['label' => 'Sign out (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')','url' => ['/site/logout'],'template' => '<a href="{url}" data-method="post">{label}</a>',],
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a question, try to explain a little bit. In this case, there are some other replies so you should exposed Cons and Pros of your P.O.V.