# Yii2: Method not allowed arror while logout action from different controller

Tags: yii2

When i am executing logging out action from

```
....index.php?r=teams/dashboard
```

it is throwing me #405 method not allowed error. DO i have to implement logout method other than site controller.. i.e in teams controller????

Comment: Did you check this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420533/yii2-method-not-allowed-405-while-logout-user

Answer (score 1):

```
 /**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [            
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

this action does not accept Get method, you should send it as Post OR remove it from VerbFilter.

```
<?= Html::a('Logout', ['/user/logout'], ['data-method'=>'post']) ?>
```