# Yii2 Logout link issue

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I used this function for logout link instead of using it on menu.

this code I used:

```
<?= Html::a('Logout', ['site/logout'], ['data-method' => 'post']) ?>
```

Showing-

> Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: POST.

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2: Method Not Allowed (#405) while logout user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420533/yii2-method-not-allowed-405-while-logout-user)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
<?= Html::a('Logout', ['site/logout'], ['data' => ['method' => 'post']]) ?>
```

See [method doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#a%28%29-detail) and [parameter detail](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#renderTagAttributes%28%29-detail).

You also have to make sure that the **YiiAsset** was loaded. This is the JS code that does the magic (links are usually producing GET requests). By default when you have generated your initial code with the Yii project templates it gets included with the [AppAsset](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#defining-asset-bundles) which in turn gets instanciated in the layout file (`AppAsset::register($this);`).

Comment: Hi **robsch**, not yet solved my problem, showing same error.

Comment: Do you have a verb filter in your controller?

Comment: No, I have no verb filter in my controller, but i added this-    use yii\filters\VerbFilter; problem is still remaining.

Comment: Most likely the JS code that handles 'data-method' is absent (YiiAsset not loaded). These two constructions are equivalent: `['data-method' => 'post']` and `['data' => ['method' => 'post']]`.

Comment: @AlSaba Without any further information, what can we do then? Come on... update your post and provide some code or tell us which error you get now.

Comment: After a long search you saved my day. Thanks@robsch